# Shared Preferences Drawable color Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, sharedpreferences, drawable, android-drawable

Hello I'm using Shared Preferences to store colors of the APP. 
Until now I can save the colors of the button and status bar because they don't use drawable colors.

This is are my functions:

```
private void storeColor(int color){
    SharedPreferences mSharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("ToolbarColor", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedpreferences.edit();
    mEditor.putInt("color", color);
    mEditor.apply();
}

private int getColor(){
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ToolbarColor", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int selectedColor = mSharedPreferences.getInt("color", getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    return selectedColor;
}
```

And I'm using them like this:

```
if (intValue == 1){
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.green_apple));
            btn_historial.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_apple));
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_apple));
            }
            storeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_apple));
        }


if(getColor() != getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)){
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.colorPrimary));
            btn_historial.setBackgroundColor(getColor());
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getColor());
            }
        }
```

Before I was using toolbar, but now I want to use the action bar.
I'm a little lost here How can I add drawable colors here?

Comment: Are you want to add color from shared preference is that your problem??

Comment: Hmm, so, do you want to add a background color to your actionbar from your sharepreferences? And are not you sure how to save a drawable in sharepreference?

Comment: @ArpitPatel yes

Comment: save you hexa code as a string in preference and set using like Color.parseColor(preference value)

Comment: @ArpitPatel how to do that? When I print line, it says                                                                                              new bgColorKey = android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@91cdd14     It doesn't read the parsed hex value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [ColorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html).

```
int color = getColor();
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
```

Comment: maybe is better `Color.parseColor(color);`

Comment: @marlonpya I think it says integer color. `Color.parseColor(color);` is for string.